# Xcode 8 iOS 10 cocos2d V3.13.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to programming and developing on cocos2d platform.

I have downloaded the latest cocos from their official website (version: V3.13.1) and created the Xcode project with cocos in terminal. I opened the ios project run the blank project, but it loaded like 200+ warnings. All warnings are all different:

```
Unused variable "40differentvariables"
"register" storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++1z
"delegate" is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

etc
etc
etc
etc..

There are so many different warnings... Is there anyone else having the same issue? These warnings are just annoying.

Anyone knows what could be the issue here?